# Override and add a link to a themed table

Tags: 7, navigation, theming

Using a custom module, I'm trying to add "Schedule" links to each of the rows of the table on node/%nid/revisions, but can't seem to figure it out.  Do I have to override the entire function node_revision_overview in node/node.pages.inc?

There is another table I would like to this to as well.  So in general, I thought this would be a good excercise to learn Drupal theming.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: What I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 0):

yes copy the whole function to one of your own and add the operation. this is not dynamic.

for the other table, if you use an entity you could add the operation via the entitycontroller, only found this for d8 in the rush .. [Custom entity operation links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82138/custom-entity-operation-links)

for the d7 way http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.ui.inc/class/EntityDefaultUIController/7