# Custom entity api admin UI overview table how to add extra columns and operations? Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I've seen this: [Custom entity operation links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82138/custom-entity-operation-links) but it's for Drupal 8 and dealing with nodes whereas mine is a non-node type entity.

So how does one go about adding stuff to the row? I want to add custom operations and basically get control of it but I can't see where to start.

I've extended `EntityDefaultUIController` in the conventional way ([like this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1021576)). When you go the administrative UI we can debug and break in `entity.ui.inc` and see the following code snippets which seems to be where this gets invoked. But I've got a feeling that there's a quicker and easier way than adding extended versions of the already existing `EntityDefaultUIController` functions. But what holds the operations & additional column row information?

**entity.ui.inc**

*within `overviewTable(...)`* ...

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
  $rows[] = $this->overviewTableRow($conditions, entity_id($this->entityType, $entity), $entity);
}
```

... which leads us to the following function (same file)

```
protected function overviewTableRow($conditions, $id, $entity, $additional_cols = array()) {
```

and we get use of $additional_cols in the 4th (0th + 3 in array speak) parameter but as you can see it's not passed as a parameter above so how do you go about getting this additional information added into the overviewTable?

```
    // Add in any passed additional cols.
    foreach ($additional_cols as $col) {
        $row[] = $col;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how do do this, and it, of course, isn't terribly straightforward...

You're on the right track, you just need to override the EntityDefaultUIController::overviewTable function in your own custom class. I don't think there's an easier way (since you're looking for one).

So, copy the the implementation of overviewTable from EntityDefaultUIController (in entity/includes/entity.ui.inc in the Entity API module) into your custom ui controller class and look for the calls to:

```
$this->overviewTableRow($conditions, entity_id($this->entityType, $entity), $entity);
```

...and add the $additional_cols parameter which should be an array populated with the extra data (which you can pull from the $entity object already populated in the foreach loop. So, do something like:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
  $additional_cols = array($entity->someField, $entity->someOtherField);
  $rows[] = $this->overviewTableRow($conditions, entity_id($this->entityType, $entity), $entity, $additional_cols);
}
```

In addition to that you'd have to add the associated headers into the render array at the end of the overviewTable function like so...

```
$additional_headers = array('some field', 'some other field');

$render = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $this->overviewTableHeaders($conditions, $rows, $additional_headers),
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('None.'),
);
```

...my guess is that you already figured out this much, but to answer your question, no, I don't think that there's an easier way. I hope this helps you, or someone else. ...or if someone knows this easier way, let me know too... =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this cleaner and with less code, override the overviewTableHeaders and overviewTableRow functions (instead of overviewTable) in your controller class.

```
class CustomEntityDefaultUIController extends EntityDefaultUIController {

    protected function overviewTableHeaders($conditions, $rows, $additional_header = array()) {
        $additional_header[] = t('My Custom Field');
        $additional_header[] = t('My Other Custom Field');
        return parent::overviewTableHeaders($conditions, $rows, $additional_header);
    }

    protected function overviewTableRow($conditions, $id, $entity, $additional_cols = array()) {
        $additional_cols[] = $entity->my_custom_field;
        $additional_cols[] = $entity->my_other_custom_field;
        return parent::overviewTableRow($conditions, $id, $entity, $additional_cols);
    }

}
```