# Custom node actions/

Tags: views

I have a view which is rendered as a table, the last column is labeled "actions" which I display both the "Edit" and "Delete" links accordingly.

I need to implement a few more custom operations, I found this as a starting point:

[Custom entity operation links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82138/custom-entity-operation-links)

Here is what I have thus far:

**module.module**

```
<?php
  function module_views_api() {
    return array(
      'api' => 3,
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module') . '/views',
    );
  }
```

**module.info**

```
files[] = views/module.views.inc
files[] = views/module_handler_print.inc
```

**module.views.inc**

```
<?php

  function module_views_data() {
    $data = array();
    $data['node']['print'] = array(
      'title' => t('Print link'),
      'help' => t('Provide a simple link to print the content.'),
      'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'module_handler_print',
      ),
    );

    return $data;
  }
```

**module_handler_print.inc**

```
<?php
  class views_handler_field_node_link_print extends views_handler_field_node_link {

    function render_link($node, $values) {
      // Ensure user has access to edit this node.
      if (!node_access('update', $node)) {
        return;
      }

      $this->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
      $this->options['alter']['path'] = "node/$node->nid/print";
      $this->options['alter']['query'] = drupal_get_destination();

      $text = !empty($this->options['text']) ? $this->options['text'] : t('print');

      return $text;
    }

  }
```

I can see the option when adding the field to VIEWS but when I select it I get the error:

> Configure field: Broken/missing handler

Any ideas???

Comment: Looks like I have to implement a views_handler_field_node_link similar to how views_handler_field_node_link_edit does...how do I register this handler though?

Comment: try to extend views_handler_field class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/ccl

or create your custom solution based on this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/juampy72/5816530)

Comment: ccl is pretty interesting...I literally just found the github code and pasted...no dice same error...I'll update my post with code thus far.